# wha'ts is the cause of an error in the below

Tags: scikit-learn

```
x,y = load_iris(return_x_y =True)

x,y = load_iris(return_x_y =True)x,y = load_iris(return_x_y =True)
```

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5332\2922518932.py in <module>
----> 1 x,y = load_iris(return_x_y =True)

TypeError: load_iris() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_x_y'
```

I'm getting Type Error  kindly let me know where I'm doing it wrong

Comment: `return_X_y` - Notice the uppercase X. Flagging this question as caused by a typo.

Comment: See [the documentation for `load_iris`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html).